# What is $\lim_{n \to \infty} 2^n \tan\left(\frac{a}{2^n}\right)$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, analysis, trigonometry

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}{2^n\cdot \tan\left(\frac{a}{2^n}\right)}$$

Experimenting with Wolfram Alpha, I came to suspect the limit is ${a}$. Any help on this matter? I couldn't find it with with half-angle formulas and the series expansion is not very productive either. A similar  result is used (without proof) in the answer of Rohan Shindes question:  Evaluate $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{r=1}^n \frac {1}{2^r}\tan \left(\frac {1}{2^r}\right)$$ yet eventhough I invested some effort, I was unable to find the solution. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference); the title is difficult to read

Comment: Your second limit, the infinite series $\sum_{r=1}^\infty\frac{1}{2^r}\tan\left(\frac{1}{2^r}\right)$, is a lot harder. Asymptotically, the terms are $\frac{1}{4^r}$, so we estimate the sum as $\frac13$. But this [certainly isn't exact](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+of+tan%281%2F2%5Er%29%2F2%5Er+from+1+to+infinity). I wouldn't expect a closed form.

Answer (score 5):

Write your term in the form $$\frac{\tan\left(\frac{a}{2^n}\right)}{\frac{a}{2^n}}\times a$$

Comment: Thank you, for the short and useful proof.

Comment: Nice that i could help you!

Answer (score -2):

For $a=0$ we obtain:
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}2^n\tan\frac{a}{2^n}=0.$$
For $a\neq0$ we obtain:
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}2^n\tan\frac{a}{2^n}=a\lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}\frac{\tan\frac{a}{2^n}}{\frac{a}{2^n}}=a,$$ which says that for all real $a$ we have:
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}2^n\tan\frac{a}{2^n}=a.$$

Comment: This is the same as the one above.

Comment: @IMOPUTFIE They are really different. For $a=0$ the solution about you say is wrong.

Comment: Can down-voter explain us why did you do it?